# How do I avoid continual issues with multiple programs (git, ruby, python) and default network drive path problems?

Tags: windows-7, git, ruby

I am not an advanced user.

Windows 7 PC. Our network admin has a network drive (H: drive)that installs on restart.....which I do not have access to when not in the office (or is not available via VPN). I have learned to both install apps after disconnecting the network drive and disconnect the network drive by default when at home.

Yet.. it seems that just about anything I install has problems that are not overt install issues. Ruby, Git and Python all install, but have problems.

The latest incarnation is the installation of Git. It installed fine, but when I tried to create a new directory, it gave me the following error

```
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
while executing
"exec {C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-config.exe} --global --add gui.recentrepo C:/Users/myname/Desktop/Testing/projects"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
```

YET... it still added files to a git folder. It would not allow me to open what I just created.

I am looking for a fix to my .git problem, but I am really looking for clues to a magic bullet on this underlying network issue that continues to be a major roadblock in making headway in my learning experience.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For machines that are part of a "windows server domain", the administrator can  (and seems to have) redirect your "Documents" folder to a folder on a file server (the H: disk) via a [group policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy).

This is generally not a good idea for laptops.

You can ask your administrator to disable folder redirection for you.
But you will than have to copy files to your H: manually if you want to have them backed up on the network.