# How does git determine the value for HOME when not set?

Tags: windows, git

Searching for "git default home directory" will easily net some third party statements that the user folder `C:\Users\<account>` is said directory.

In practise, this generally holds: Grab a Windows PC without Git, install Git from any source, set a variable in global config => `C:\Users\<account>\.gitconfig` is created and read by Git.

Now for the second time, I have a system here, where this path spuriously changes to `H:\.gitconfig` and back - H: being a network drive accessible only via Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

Defining HOME overrides this behaviour, but

- [it messes up unrelated things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows#comment27741402_4051282)
- I would like to understand **what happens**.

I was not able to find official documentation on this matter, although I expect it must exist.

Reasons I was able to exclude:

- It is not USERPROFILE - that variable never changes away from `C:\Users\<account>`.
- It is not a [conditional configuration include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884702).
- There is no HOME set directly [in the profile file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115116/3434465).
- There was no HOME environmental variable defined before I added mine.
- It is not a [corrupted PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/1273334/gitconfig-not-being-generated-in-windows-7-machine?rq=1#comment1879411_1273378).

Might or might not be related:

- So far I have only seen this interaction with Cisco AnyConnect VPN (not other VPN clients) and a network drive called H: (not other network drive letters).
- `git --version` is 2.40.0.windows.1 on the machine currently exhibiting this issue. (I no longer have access to the older one, but I think it had about 2.24.x.windows.y .)
- All uses of Git have been via cmd.
- The respective IT departments providing either affected machine claimed to not have any configuration (e.g. [group policies](https://superuser.com/a/683649)) in place, that could explain (aka cause) this behaviour. (And indeed, outside of git, no program seems to automatically put files onto H: - there is only what I put there manually *and* vestigial files .gitconfig, .lesshst, .viminfo created whenever I dare to use Git at the wrong time.)
- I have colleagues who claim it does not happen on their machines, even though nominally those should be configured identically.
- [Other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows#comment50063174_4050905) have reported their global .gitconfig to reside on network drives, but none of them noted the location to *move around*. The well-known/expected/normal way this happens is that USERPROFILE and all point to the network drive and trying to use programs offline simply produces hard errors (there is no automatic fallback to a different path).

Comment: @Destroy666 : Ah, sorry for not reporting back. I have a bit of a problem here: I checked everything in this answer, and while factually correct, none of that seemed to be the reason on my machine. But then I noticed that, despite the administrator's assertion that this was nothing on their end, the behaviour had simply _disappeared_ . Originally I had to define %HOME% to prevent it, but now I no longer need to. So... I have no clue whether that answer was right or not, because I did not catch whatever had to change to fix the issue.

Comment: @Destroy666 : I'll upvote though, as with the link to the source I could have written a MVE that would emit the read directory, _had_ the issue remained reproducible.
Given this is the third machine at the second company where I saw this exact same behaviour, I may eventually be able to come back to it at the next job/project, but it will be a while.

Answer (score 1):

It is stated how the path is determined e.g. in the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES):

> By default, `git config` will read configuration options from multiple
> files:
>
> `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`
> System-wide configuration file.
>
> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`
> `~/.gitconfig`
> User-specific configuration
> files. When the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable is not set or
> empty, `$HOME/.config/` is used as `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.
>
> These are also called "global" configuration files. If both files
> exist, both files are read in the order given above.
>
> `$GIT_DIR/config`
> Repository specific configuration file.
>
> `$GIT_DIR/config.worktree`
> This is optional and is only searched when
> `extensions.worktreeConfig` is present in `$GIT_DIR/config`.
>
> You may also provide additional configuration parameters when running
> any git command by using the `-c` option. See [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) for details.
>
> Options will be read from all of these files that are available. If
> the global or the system-wide configuration files are missing or
> unreadable they will be ignored. If the repository configuration file
> is missing or unreadable, `git config` will exit with a non-zero error
> code. An error message is produced if the file is unreadable, but not
> if it is missing.
>
> The files are read in the order given above, with last value found
> taking precedence over values read earlier. When multiple values are
> taken then all values of a key from all files will be used.
>
> By default, options are only written to the repository specific
> configuration file. Note that this also affects options like
> `--replace-all` and `--unset`. `git config` **will only ever change one file at a time**.
>
> You can limit which configuration sources are read from or written to
> by specifying the path of a file with the `--file` option, or by
> specifying a configuration scope with `--system`, `--global`, `--local` or
> `--worktree`. For more, see [OPTIONS](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#OPTIONS) above.

So administrator could just use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` env to override it, for instance. Which doesn't seem to be the case here looking at the file name you listed.

`GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` env listed [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#ENVIRONMENT) can be used to override the user locations, too:

> `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL`
> `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`
> Take the configuration from the given files instead from global or    system-level configuration files. If `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM` is set, the    system config file defined at build time (usually `/etc/gitconfig`)     will not be read. Likewise, if `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` is set, neither
> `$HOME/.gitconfig` nor `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` will be read. Can  be set to `/dev/null` to skip reading configuration files of the
> respective level.

It could also even be a customized git build that modifies [this file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79bdd48716a4c455bdc8ffd91d57a18d5cd55baa/config.c) and maybe some others to read the config in a different way.